# Commas and conversational clauses

Tags: grammar, commas, dialogue

I'm editing an article, and a piece of dialogue is giving me some trouble.

> You were practically a co-owner you’d been there so long.

Is this written correctly, or would a comma break up those two clauses? I.e.:

> You were practically a co-owner, you’d been there so long.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would use a comma. (But it's not *essential*.) If you want a single phrase without a comma, then reverse the components: *You were there so long that you were practically a co-owner.*

Comment: Or: *You were practically a co-owner, **as** you’d been there so long.*

Comment: If you were to retain the current wording, the punctuation needs to change: the comma needs to be replaced by either a semi-colon or an n-dash.